# Exponents to math symbols with mathbb

Tags: amsmath, mathbb

I am using the amsfont package where I can use mathbb to format for instance the symbol for real numbers as follows

```
$\mathbb{R}$
```

I want however to include exponents, though my approach so far looks quite terrible:

```
$\mathbb{R}^{nx1}$
```

How can this be resolved? Thanks

Comment: Why is this result terrible? What is it that you would want?

Comment: It should be `\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}`

Comment: @egreg or `\mathbb{R}^{n} `?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's a notation sometimes used for denoting the *n*-row, 1-column matrices.

Comment: @egreg yes I guessed that's what it meant (although not a notation I'm familiar with:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want to use `\times` instead of `x` (which is always wrong for denoting any kind of multiplication):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} % or just amsfonts

\begin{document}

Wrong notation: $\mathbb{R}^{nx1}$

Right notation: $\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$

\end{document}
```

[image]